# Laravel routing doesn't work

Tags: laravel

This is my route.php file:

```
Route::get('/users', function () {
    return 'Users!';
});
```

But when I enter the url:

```
http://localhost:63342/quickstart/public/users
```

I get a 404 not found exception.

But if I change

```
Route::get('/users', function ()
```

to

```
Route::get('/', function ()
```

The following url functions well:

```
http://localhost:63342/quickstart/public/index.php
```

Comment: Have you set your .htaccess accordingly ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Route::get('users', function () {
    return 'Users!';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the:
/quickstart/public/

and just use:

http://localhost:63342/users